# How can i access only the text of a comment?

Tags: comments

In the comment.tpl.php there is

```
<?php
    print render($content);
 ?>
```

and this converts to this html

```
<span rel="sioc:reply_of" resource="/drupal/?q=node/5" class="rdf-meta" data-thmr="thmr_44">
</span>
<div class="field field-name-comment-body field-type-text-long field-label-hidden" data-thmr="thmr_49">
 <div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
   <p>THE COMMENT</p>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

What can i do if only want text "THE COMMENT" printed and not all this html?
I know $content is an array but can't find a way to dig into it's elements.

Comment: Hi, welcome to DA! "I know $content is an array but can't find a way to dig into it's elements." This makes it a basic PHP/programming question, and has nothing to do with Drupal itself. I'd say that makes it off-topic, and you should consult an intro to php. :)

Comment: you are right about this.I am a total newb in php.Anyway the dsm($content) helped a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and try `dpm($content);`

This will give you an easy way to browse that array.

Comment: A note from the devel module: dsm() is a legacy function that was poorly named; use dpm() instead, since the 'p' maps to 'print_r'. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4054396/784877